# Query takes too long

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, rdbms

I have the followind query:

```
SELECT *
FROM document d
INNER JOIN users_documents ud ON d.id = ud.document_id 
WHERE (d.document_state_id=2
       AND ud.sharing_type_id=1
       AND ud.user_id=:id
       AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.upload_datetime AND d.approval_end_time
       AND ud.approval=2)
OR(d.document_state_id=1
   AND ud.sharing_type_id=2
   AND ud.user_id=:id
   AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.active_start_time AND d.active_end_time 
   AND ud.approval=2)
ORDER BY ud.application_date;
```

The problem is, that it takes around 800 ms. When I changed the end of query to:

```
ORDER BY ud.uploadDatetime;
```

And I added index: upload_datetime (table document), now the query takes around 70 ms. The problem is that I REALLY need to sort the data according to ud.application_date.
I tried to add an index: application_date (on table users_documents), but It did not help (it still takes 800 ms). Which index should I use to lower this time? or what should I do? I am using MySQL.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit:
Query explanation: Query returns new documents for given user with some id. It returns documents for "approving" (sharing_type=1) and for reading (sharing_type=2), approval=2 (user has not seen the document), approval=1 (user approved the document), 0=disapproved; upload_datetime=the timestamp of uploading the document to the system; approver_end_time=document can be approved by users till this date; activeStartTime=after approval, document will show up to other users from this date TO date (=activeEndTime). 
Structure

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `po_db`.`document_state`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `po_db`.`document_state` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `po_db`.`document`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `po_db`.`document` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `active_end_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `active_start_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `approval_end_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `resource_path` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `upload_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `document_state_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `UK_36vs45u76s1n950kwxfa5lyhc` (`name` ASC),
  INDEX `FK1rwpvwxw2bvldt30kwfcbf57l` (`document_state_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FKjhdxdv9sijhujiynqbb5jc010` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `title` (`title` ASC),
  INDEX `upload` USING BTREE (`upload_datetime`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1rwpvwxw2bvldt30kwfcbf57l`
    FOREIGN KEY (`document_state_id`)
    REFERENCES `po_db`.`document_state` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKjhdxdv9sijhujiynqbb5jc010`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `po_db`.`user` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `po_db`.`sharing_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `po_db`.`sharing_type` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

and

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `po_db`.`users_documents`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `po_db`.`users_documents` (
  `document_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `sharing_type_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `application_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `approval` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_sent` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`document_id`, `sharing_type_id`, `user_id`),
  INDEX `FK4mt7odsubst5269c4djnj4jip` (`sharing_type_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FKtn1i27tltfpy3n4pe306vtwu9` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `historie_dok` (`approval` ASC, `sharing_type_id` ASC, `user_id` ASC, `application_date` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK4mt7odsubst5269c4djnj4jip`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sharing_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `po_db`.`sharing_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK6abpoybb0f2ydy6ufla1wo80x`
    FOREIGN KEY (`document_id`)
    REFERENCES `po_db`.`document` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKtn1i27tltfpy3n4pe306vtwu9`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `po_db`.`user` (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Edit 2: 
I changed the end of the query to:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN d.document_state_id=2 THEN d.upload_datetime ELSE d.active_start_time END;
```

its basically the same as with application_date, but it still goes slowly (300 ms, but its better than 800ms).

I tried to add index (table document): `document_state_id, upload_datetime, active_start_time`

but it does not help at all again... :/

Comment: well, if you added index for `document.upload_datetime`, it makes sense to add it for `document.approval_end_time` as well. I suspect that the bottleneck is `current_timestamp()` function, which is probably executed for each row

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: @Strawberry structue added.

Comment: An EXPLAIN is found by executing 'EXPLAIN [your query]'

Comment: How many rows in each table??

Comment: Shouldn't `ud.uploadDatetime` be `d.uploadDatetime`??  In which case that helps explain the diff timing (but not the "why").

Comment: Please do `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both cases.

Comment: If you don't need _all_ the columns from each table, trim down the `*`.  This _may_ allow some extra optimizations.

Comment: Is `user_id` the same in both tables??  If so, that is redundant.  And, if so, we could consider `JOINing` on it (plus other columns).  If not, then you get two different "user_ids" when doing `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A:**  Turn the `OR` into a `UNION`:

```
    ( SELECT  *
            FROM  document d
            INNER JOIN  users_documents ud  ON d.id = ud.document_id
            WHERE  d.document_state_id=2
              AND  ud.sharing_type_id=1
              AND  ud.user_id=:id
              AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.upload_datetime
                                           AND d.approval_end_time
              AND  ud.approval=2
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  *
            FROM  document d
            INNER JOIN  users_documents ud  ON d.id = ud.document_id
            WHERE  d.document_state_id=1
              AND  ud.sharing_type_id=2
              AND  ud.user_id=:id
              AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.active_start_time
                                           AND d.active_end_time
              AND  ud.approval=2 
    )
    ORDER BY  application_date;
```

That way, each SELECT can make good use of the index starting with approval ASC, sharing_type_id ASC, user_id ASC. (The 4th column does not help.)

**Plan B:**  Use "covering indexes":

```
SELECT d2.*, ud2.*
  FROM (
    ( SELECT  id, document_id, sharing_type_id, user_id
            FROM  document d
            INNER JOIN  users_documents ud  ON d.id = ud.document_id
            WHERE  d.document_state_id=2
              AND  ud.sharing_type_id=1
              AND  ud.user_id=:id
              AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.upload_datetime 
                                           AND d.approval_end_time
              AND  ud.approval=2
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT  id, document_id, sharing_type_id, user_id
            FROM  document d
            INNER JOIN  users_documents ud  ON d.id = ud.document_id
            WHERE  d.document_state_id=1
              AND  ud.sharing_type_id=2
              AND  ud.user_id=:id
              AND  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN d.active_start_time
                                           AND d.active_end_time
              AND  ud.approval=2 
    )
       )
  JOIN document d2  USING(id)
  JOIN users_documents ud2  USING(document_id, sharing_type_id, user_id)
  ORDER BY  ud2.application_date;
```

Plus these new indexes; the order is important:

```
UD: INDEX(approval, sharing_type_id, user_id, document_id)  -- document_id last
D: INDEX(document_state_id, approval_end_time, approval_start_time, document_id)
D: INDEX(document_state_id, active_end_time, active_start_time, document_id)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot use UNION in my query, because JPA is required and It does not support UNION :(

Comment: I tried the query in MySQL workbench and I am getting this error: Error Code: 1250. Table 'ud' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
Do you have any idea, how to get rid of this error?

Comment: @Sirdhemond - fixed 2 typos